# ggplot2: theme_void() throws warnings when used with theme_set()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm just wondering why `ggplot2` complains about missing elements when I try to set the default theme to `theme_void`? Should not that be okay, am I missing something?

```
library(ggplot2)

theme_set(theme_classic()) ## OK, no warnings

theme_set(theme_void())
##  Warning message:
##  New theme missing the following elements: axis.title.x, axis.title.x.top, axis.title.y, axis.title.y.right, axis.text.x, axis.text.x.top, axis.text.y, axis.text.y.right, axis.ticks, axis.line, axis.line.x, axis.line.y, legend.background, legend.margin, legend.spacing, legend.spacing.x, legend.spacing.y, legend.key, legend.key.height, legend.key.width, legend.text.align, legend.title.align, legend.direction, legend.justification, legend.box.margin, legend.box.background, legend.box.spacing, panel.background, panel.border, panel.spacing.x, panel.spacing.y, panel.grid, panel.grid.minor, plot.background, strip.background, strip.placement, strip.text.x, strip.text.y
```

Comment: It's fine, the warning is just telling you that a bunch of standard chart elements are missing from the theme, which is the point of `theme_void()`.

Comment: If you don't want to see the warning, you can add the theme to the plot `plot1 + theme_void()` instead

Comment: But I want to add a chart with a voided theme in a vignette of my package, will this warning cause problem when I check the package?

Comment: @Mako212 - Adding the theme manually to each plot is not clean enough for me